# Recursive list filling in python

Tags: python

Sometimes I need to fill lists recursively and to this point I have always done it like this (simple example, this should also work for complex recursive lists, e.g. exponential moving averages):

```
In [1]: def complex_func(a,b):
   ...:     return a + b
   ...: 
   ...: recursive_list = [1, 2]
   ...: for i in range(9):
   ...:     recursive_list.append(complex_func(
   ...:         recursive_list[-2],
   ...:         recursive_list[-1]
   ...:     ))
   ...: recursive_list
Out[1]: [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144]
```

Is there a way to do this better? And with better I mean more pythonic or even faster. I have the feeling that this is not the best way.

Maybe something like this (which is not working):

```
In [1]: recursive_list = [1, 2, complex_func(
   ...:         recursive_list[-2],
   ...:         recursive_list[-1]
   ...:     ) for i in range(9)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the extend method:

```
def complex_func(a,b): return a+b

L = [1,2]
L.extend(complex_func(*L[-2:]) for _ in range(9))

print(L)
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144]
```

If the operation is commutative, you could even start with an empty list by providing default values to the function arguments:

```
def complex_func(a=0,b=1): return a+b

L = []
L.extend(complex_func(*L[-2:]) for _ in range(10))
                
print(L)
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
```

Comment: Yes thank you! That was exactly what I was looking for. A completely different approach not using append.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `range`.

```py
start = 1
times = 9
res = list(range(start, start + times + 1))
print(res)
```

Comment: The list could be way more complex than this. Sorry my bad, should have said that. So its not an easy listing of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you need recursion. You only refer to a single value at the end of the list, so you just need a variable to track that value.

```
seed = 1
my_list = []
for i in range(10):
    my_list.append(seed)
    seed = seed + 1
```

If you don't mind an external module, install `more-itertools` and use `iterate`:

```
>>> from more_itertools import iterate
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> list(islice(iterate(lambda x: x + 1, 1), 10))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

For the Fibonacci numbers, use two seeds:

```
seed1 = 0  # my_list[-2]
seed2 = 1  # my_list[-1]
my_list = []
for i in range(10):
    my_list.append(seed1)
    seed1, seed2 = seed2, seed1 + seed2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not my problem here. It is not about the specific list but about a recursive list which could be really complex. I edited my question, hope it makes it more clear.

Comment: You don't need recursion, because whatever your fixed offsets into the list are, you can use separate variables that get updated in the loop.

Comment: But I dont want to use append again like in my example. I want to use something more pythonic or even faster.

Comment: Actual recursion is a bad idea, because it's both slow and will eventually produce a `RecursionError`. For something like this, iteration is both faster and more pythonic.

Comment: So you would say that appending to a list is actually the fastest way? Because I need to fill recursive lists with up to 10^7 entries and I always had the feeling that appending this often cant be optimal.

Comment: Appending isn't really significantly slower than using a list comprehension. List comprehensions, though, cannot refer to themselves.